# Angular - Store multiple Get request in one json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, get

I have a problem with an issue. I want to store the info of multiple `GET` request in one `JSON` and I need some advice. I have two calls in my app, the first call gives me some values for each element, something like this:

```
//values: Number [] =[]; 
this._ValuesService.getValues().subscribe(
          result => {
            this.values= result;
          },
          err => console.log(err)
        );
```

And the second `GET` is like that :

```
//calcs: Calcs[] = []; 
this._CalcsService.getCalcs(value)
          .subscribe(
            res => {
              this.calcs= res;
            },
            err => {
              console.log(err);
              alert('Error =C');
            }
          );
```

I want to do at the same time `GET` calls to `CalcsService` for each value in `Values[]` and store it in only one `JSON`. I consider the option to use `ForkJoin`, but I think that is not the solution to this problem. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two calls will be two results, unless you merge them somehow. But what is the reason you would want to do it? Just wait for both to finish and then handle the results. It feels like you're trying to solve a problem that might not really be a problem.

Comment: Why not ForkJoin? I think it solves your problem

Comment: `forkJoin` wont produce 1 single JSON but an array with two separate JSON results.

Comment: You can use the zip operator more information here -> https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511

Comment: also after forkJoin you can use map or reduce on the result to generate one json from the array

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean all results from calcs, and not mixed result from calc + values. Try the following:

```
this._ValuesService.getValues()
  .map(values => values.map(value => this._CalcsService.getCalcs(value)) // Create an Observable foreach value
  .switchMap(obs => Observable.combineLatest(obs)) // Call the endpoint foreach value
  .subscribe(result => { // Array of results from calc
    console.log(result);
  });
```